# Where to store the Python virtualenv of a system-wide installed application

Tags: linux, python, virtualenv

You're deploying a Python application that uses its own virtualenv with libraries different from the system installed libraries, and you need to install those libraries the best way possible.

I ask this because it's clear that the binary is going to go to `/usr/local/bin`, and the application assets to `/usr/local/share/application` but I don't know if there's a convention that kind of data.

Where do you store the virtualenv? `/usr/local/share/application`, `/srv/application`, `/var/local/application`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Traditionally I would say

```
/usr/[local]/libexec/application
```

https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/ch04s07.html

https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/Directory-Variables.html

Recent Distros may not use a separate libexec directory anymore and simply use `/usr/lib[64]`. If you are using a build system like autoconf/automake you could use the variable $(libexecdir) and it will be  correct on any Distro.